# Version vs Distrib number of MySQL

Tags: mysql

Typing the

```
mysql --version
```

command in a Linux shell, I got the following:

```
mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.77, for redhat-linux-gnu (i686) using readline 5.1
```

The number 5.0.77 obviously refers to the known version number of MySQL. What does 14.12 mean?

Is this documented/explained anywhere?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

**Ver** refers to the version of the mysql command line client - what you are envoking by typing 'mysql'
**Distrib** refers to the mysql server version your client was *built with*.  This is not to be confused with the mysql server you are connected to, which can be obtained with `SELECT VERSION();`

The mysql client (what you are evoking) is distributed with the server, and, AFAIK, there is no easy way to build it on it's own.

I can't find any documentation for this either, so the source is the only 'source' of documentation.

First stop: client/mysql.cc:  the mysql client.

```
    static void usage(int version)
    {
    ...
    printf("%s  Ver %s Distrib %s, for %s (%s) using %s %s\n",
             my_progname, VER, MYSQL_SERVER_VERSION, SYSTEM_TYPE, MACHINE_TYPE,
             readline, rl_library_version);
```

As you see, it uses the constants VER for "14.12" and MYSQL_SERVER_VERSION for "5.0.77"

Where are these constants defined?, is the question.

VER is defined near the top (line 51 in my source) of client/mysql.cc as a constant at run time.

```
const char *VER= "14.14";
```

And I would assume, updated by hand or by a checkin process. This is very likely the version of the 'client' because it's right there in the client code.

MYSQL_SERVER_VERSION is defined in include/mysql_version.h (line 12) which is used for both the client and server (mysql / mysqld)

```
#define MYSQL_SERVER_VERSION            "5.1.56"
```

(it's actually set in the configure script and substituted in at configure time)

Comment: Thanks... Although if someone can find official documentation on this from MySQL, I think a link to that is a better answer than spelunking the code.