# Can't reset root password with --skip-grant-tables on ubuntu 16

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, root, change-password

I am trying to reset the root password following [MysqlPasswordReset](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset) but when I try to start the server with --skip-grant-tables the server doesn't start

- Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-59-generic x86_64)
- mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.17, for Linux (x86_64)

Server is running

```
$ mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Stop server

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
[ ok ] Stopping mysql (via systemctl): mysql.service.
```

Trying to start with --skip-grant-tables

```
sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
[1] 9856
```

Connect with no password

```
$ mysql -u root
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
[1]+  Exit 1                  sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking
```

I also tried to start with mysql_safe (error.log is empty)

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
2017-02-01T16:33:31.382105Z mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
2017-02-01T16:33:31.383942Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
2017-02-01T16:33:31.386058Z mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.
2017-02-01T16:33:31.388009Z mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11657829/error-2002-hy000-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-socket-var-run)

Comment: when using safe mode could you make connection using root? Did you try without the `--skip-networking`?

Comment: @davejal Yes, I tried without --skip-networking and I can't connect to the mysql server in safe mode

Answer (score 170, accepted):

I found that the mysql.sock is deleted when the mysql service is stoped and mysqld_safe can't create it (I couldn't find the reason), so my solution was back up the sock folder and restore before start mysqld_safe

Start server

```
$ sudo service mysql start
```

Go to sock folder

```
$ cd /var/run
```

Back up the sock

```
$ sudo cp -rp ./mysqld ./mysqld.bak
```

Stop server

```
$ sudo service mysql stop
```

Restore the sock

```
$ sudo mv ./mysqld.bak ./mysqld
```

Start mysqld_safe

```
$ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
```

Init mysql shell

```
mysql -u root
```

Change password

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

SET PASSWORD FOR root@'localhost' = PASSWORD('my_new_password');
```

Comment: I had to set the password that way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37879448/mysql-fails-on-mysql-error-1524-hy000-plugin-auth-socket-is-not-loaded#answer-37879449

Comment: On last command got `ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin 'auth_socket' is not loaded` on Kubuntu 18.04

Comment: I believe this method is easier – https://superuser.com/a/1175035/320611

Comment: In mysql 5.7.24, the password column must be changed to authentication_string

Comment: after doing this mysql server didn't start

Comment: Thanks, I've been searching for a while for a solution to a newly installed mysql service on Debian 19.10. This is the first solution that actually worked.

Comment: I had to reboot linux as I couldn't start the service again after doing this. All working now, thank you!

Comment: This doesn't work for Ubuntu 16.04 MySQL Community Server

Comment: God bless you. Worked like a charm

Answer (score 60):

For Ubuntu 19 with MySQL 8.0.17-0ubuntu2, what ended up working for me was a combination of many answers:

1. In the MySQL's configuration file (`/etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf` on my machine), under `[mysqld]`, add:

   `skip-grant-tables = 1
   plugin-load-add = auth_socket.so`
2. Restart the MySQL Service;
3. Connect to MySQL: `mysql -uroot`;
4. Run:

> ```
> UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=null WHERE User='root';
> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
>
> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'pass123';
> ```

5. Stop MySQL and comment `skip-grant-tables` in the configuration file;
6. Start MySQL again and this should now work: `mysql -u root -ppass123`.

Comment: Note that if you see that the `UPDATE` statement did not alter any rows (e.g. `Query OK, 0 rows affected`) it means you don't have a root user. In that case follow the instructions in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709078/how-can-i-restore-the-mysql-root-user-s-full-privileges) to create it before running these queries again.

Comment: I cannot tell you how long I blundered around for before I found this answer. Thank you.

Comment: `mysql: [ERROR] unknown variable 'skip-grant-tables=1'`

Comment: @logicbloke It should be enough to simply put: `skip-grant-tables`

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!! This answer saved my bacon today.

Comment: The accepted answer didn't work for me (mysld_safe just kept exiting right away with no useful error) but this answer worked perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! Tried to solve this problem for more than one day.

Comment: I totally fall in line with the previous acknowledgements, thanks so much! Finally I solved this issue after several hours.

Comment: After a dozen different attempts, this is the one that worked.

Comment: This is what helped me. Nothing else worked. Not even the official advice of running MySQL in safe mode with command line options and init-file.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Ubuntu 20.  Mysql 8.0.26 ... Tried so many things. This finally worked !

Comment: I tried the most upvoted (backup the sock) solution and it did not work however this did perfectly. Server version: 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 (Ubuntu)

Answer (score 5):

[pedronalbert's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41987711/7311767) answer above worked for me but the last step is now deprecated and throws the following warning:

> Warning | 1287 | 'SET PASSWORD FOR  = PASSWORD('')' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET PASSWORD FOR  = '' instead

Use this command instead:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR root = '<plaintext_password>';
```

Comment: looks like they have removed an important functionality. with `--skip-grant-tables` the auth plugin is not loaded, and we cannot use `set password`, so there is no way to seems to revert the password. looks like we need to execute `password('password')` on a old mysql server, and copy paste the auth string, and update the table manually.

Answer (score 4):

I tried many ways including @pedronalbert 's but still not working.

The way I solved it is adding "*skip-grant-tables*" in */etc/my.cnf* then start mysql service and connecting mysql with *"mysql -u root*" as 
https://www.codero.com/knowledge-base/content/33/296/en/how-to-reset-your-root-mysql-password.html

It works in my VM CentOS 7.

Comment: This method of configuring `skip-grant-tables` also works for Ubuntu 19 and MySQL 8.

Comment: This answer doesn't go into enough detail and will most likely not work. You can't just add `skip-grant-tables` randomly like it says. Check the answer below for the actual complete process to use.