# Cannot login to MySQL using sudo as root

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I'm having a weird problem where I cannot login to my MySQL server with sudo as root on a ubuntu 19.10 server. I want to be able to reset my root password.

The error message I got was:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Anyone had similar problems? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'bill'@'localhost' (using password: YES)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299148/mysql-error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-billlocalhost-using-passw)

Comment: If you don't recall your root password and for whatever reason `mysql` isn't letting you in from your root user's shell, you may need to shut down mysql and then restart after toggling [`skip-grant-tables`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41984956/cant-reset-root-password-with-skip-grant-tables-on-ubuntu-16) and restarting.This starts the server and allows anyone to log in without using credentials (so.. if this is a live database other folks are accessing... be careful). Then you can connect again, change your root password, exit, and toggle the setting and restart the service normally.

Comment: Somehow I cannot seem to be able to start mysqld with: "sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables". The system is not returning any errors but just refuse to start.

Comment: An "ERROR 1045 Access denied" shows that your mysql service is already running, so you won't be able to start it again.

Comment: Is this a fresh install? Did you set that mysql password before or you are trying to use the Linux root user's password?

Comment: The link in my comment describes exactly the way to toggle that setting in Ubuntu 19.04 (where the --skip-grant-tables doesn't work).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok - so I solved this problem myself.

The correct way of resetting the root password for mysql is to:

1. Stop all mysql server sessions.
2. Start mysqld manually using - this basically tells MySQL to skip any credentials check and allow anyone to login, hence you want to skip-networking to avoid network users.

`sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking`

3. Use this to login as root:

`sudo mysql -u root`

4. In the mysql prompt, do:

`FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
SET PASSWORD FOR root@'localhost' = PASSWORD('password');
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

5. Stop mysqld and restart mysql normally (you may need to kill the mysqld process).

In my case, there was some problems with the installation and the /var/run/mysqld folder was not correctly set up. It may be a bug with MySQL and it was not properly reported.

After creating the folder with the correct setmod (user:group is mysql:mysql) mysqld runs without any problem.