# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' : even though I used sudo

Tags: mysql, error-handling, terminal, permission-denied

```
~ mysql -u root -p
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

~ sudo mysql -u root -p
Password:
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Eventhough I tried sudo it's not working. What should I have to do to fix this problem?

Comment: Could be you need to reset the root password https://stackoverflow.com/a/60384009/2310830

Comment: @RiggsFolly I tried `sudo mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking`, but even this one cause error.

Comment: The same error or a different one

Comment: `[ERROR] [MY-010123] [Server] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!
2023-02-08T17:45:42.719900Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting`

Comment: I assume you stopped the MySQL Server before trying that?

Comment: Yes, I stopped mysql using `sudo mysql.server stop`