# PHPMyAdmin Configuration not working because of MySQL user password?

Tags: mysql, configuration, phpmyadmin, installation, debian

**Hello stackoverflow-community!**

When I try to install and afterwards configure my phpmyadmin on my debian server I always get this error-message.

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
  corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
  near 'IDENTIFIED BY 'debian123'' at line 1
```

[here a screenshot of it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ov4EC.png)

I am using: **debian version: 9** ; **MySql version: 8.0.19**

What I tried:

- deleted phpmyadmin and reinstalled it
- tried another statement to grant privileges to the user

I hope you can help me with my problem, because I am struggeling with it quite a while.

thank you in advance

~HTL_Krems_Engineer

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using, and how are you installing it (from the Debian repository directory, through backports, or the phpMyAdmin PPA, etc)?

Comment: 1. How can I check wihich version I have in phpMyAdmin when I don#t have it properly installed ? (can't login)
Or do you mean the MySql version: 8.0.19 ?
2. Did it trough the the backports

Comment: `dpkg -l phpmyadmin` will show you the version information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a change with newer versions of MySQL.

You can no longer use `grant x on y.z to username identified by 'debian123'`.

You have to split the user creation [into multiple steps.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50197630/6632744)

Your MySQL should look like this instead:

```sql
mysql> CREATE USER 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'root';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I tried this once before and two minutes ago and it still doesn't work :(
P.S.: Same error

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like perhaps you've got an older phpMyAdmin installed, which could happen because by default the backports repository is pinned to 100. You have to use a command like `apt-get -t stretch-backports install phpmyadmin` to force the newer version to install.

Stretch comes with phpMyAdmin 4.6.6, and perhaps the post-install script (the screenshot you've attached) doesn't know the newer syntax for creating users for recent MySQL versions. The backports version is 4.9.5, which is better meant for the newer MySQL variants.

One alternative workaround would be to to answer no to the question asking if you want the package manager to create the phpMyAdmin database, then to either not use the advanced features at all or [manually create the controluser and linked tables](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#manual-configuration).