# Grant all privileges to root user in MySQL 8.0.21

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064, mysql-8.0

I am aware that this question has been asked already on stackoverflow but I don't see any answer for the actual question posted. Hence posting again.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'abcd' WITH GRANT OPTION;
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'::1' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'abcd' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Above lines throw

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD 'abcd' WITH GRANT OP' at line 1
```

I am trying to upgrade mysql from 5.7 to latest 8.0.21

Thanks!

Comment: old post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50177216/how-to-grant-all-privileges-to-root-user-in-mysql-8-0

Answer (score 2):

For `GRANT ALL` privileges to root user use the following syntax:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

The above grant mysql command defines that:

- GRANT the PRIVILEGES of type ALL
- These privileges are for a particular database named `dbname` and it applies to all tables of that database indicated by the .* that follows the dbname.
- These privileges are assigned to username when that username is connected through locally, as specified by @'localhost'.
- You can change to specify any valid host, replace 'localhost' with '%'.

Comment: Are you sure this will work for MySql 8 ? Also I want to grant PRIVILEGES to all databases. Can you please explain why the statements I have don't work ?  Note - Privileges assigned through GRANT choice don't want FLUSH PRIVILEGES to take effect.