# SQLException : Access denied for user 'utilisateur1'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, sqlexception

```js
package com.exmaven2;

import java.sql.*;


public class MainApp 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/baseune"; 
        String userName = "utilisateur1";
        String password = "password";
        
        try { 
            java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password); 
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```

Hello, I'm actually trying to connect to MySQL with a Maven project build in Eclipse IDE. I wrote this code that should let me connect to my server but I'm getting the error described in the title. I just began learning about databases and MySQL so I don't really know what to do. I already checked the privileges for 'utilisateur1' (somebody else posted the same question but this answer didn't work for me) and i have them all so I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know if it's connected with your problem but you need to add the driver  - Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Comment: I just have to write this in the main() ?

Comment: Add the block of code inside your try/catch

Comment: I got the following error : 
Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary. - Actually idk if it is an error or not, it is written in red

Answer (score 0):

could you please try this,

```
package com.exmaven2;

import java.sql.*;
public class MainApp 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/baseune?useSSL=false"; 
        String userName = "utilisateur1";
        String password = "password";
        
        try { 
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, userName, password); 
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for answering.
I tried it and  I got the following error :

java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Public Key Retrieval is not allowed

Comment: your welcome, ok could you please try this String url =  "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/baseune?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false";

Comment: The previous error disappeared but the "SQLException : Access denied for user (...)" is still here...

Comment: in mysql could you please try by granting privileges e.g GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON baseune.* TO 'utilisateur1'@'localhost';

Comment: I've got : "Error code: 1410. You are not allowed to create a user with GRANT"
I selected current_user() which is 'root' so I should be allowed idk why it says not allowed

Comment: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50177216/how-to-grant-all-privileges-to-root-user-in-mysql-8-0   could you please refer this

Comment: I created a new user and the connection worked. Thanks for your help