# SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698]

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, ubuntu-16.04

How can I overcome this error ?

> **Error:** SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users`
>   where `email` = email@gmail.com

*I'm using Ubuntu*

Please help

Comment: The error says access denied : do you use the correct password to connect and do you have right to access this database ?

Comment: I used the correct username, which is roor. Then i have no password.

Comment: Sometimes the root login without password is disabled. you may need to set a root password. have a look here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/default-privileges.html

Comment: Logging in as root is never a good idea and shouldn't be used for general purpose operations.  You should create a user in MySQL with the bare minimum permissions needed for whatever it is that your application does

Comment: put your .env file code

Comment: APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=code
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=http://localhost

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

Comment: Ensure that when you have edited the `*.env` file in your laravel application run `php artisan config:clear` and `php artisan cache:clear` to reset the config files to the new values.

Answer (score 17):

Login as root first:

```
$ sudo mysql -u root
```

Then CREATE or ALTER a non-root user (use '127.0.0.1' instead of 'localhost' if needed):

```
CREATE USER 'admin'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'adminspassword';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'admin'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Exit and restart:

```
exit
$sudo service mysql restart
$sudo service apache2 restart
```

And edit the .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3630
DB_DATABASE=yourdbname
DB_USERNAME=admin
DB_PASSWORD=adminspassword
```

Comment: After a lot of breaking my head with different solutions, this seems to have worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

MySQL will make a difference between "localhost" and "127.0.0.1".

It might be possible that 'root'@'localhost' is not allowed because there is an entry in the user table that will only allow root login from 127.0.0.1.

This could also explain why some application on your server can connect to the database and some not because there are different ways of connecting to the database. And you currently do not allow it through "localhost".

Answer (score 1):

I know its late however looking for answers, I couldn't find anything and at last I got this answer.

```
$sudo mysql -u root
[mysql] use mysql;
[mysql] update user set plugin='' where User='root';
[mysql] flush privileges;
[mysql] \q
```

Now you should be able to log in as root.
Thanks @Matematikisto in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36864206/sqlstatehy000-1698-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost) thread

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem in MySQL 8, Ubuntu 20. By default, the policy does not grant "GRANT" rights, including for root, but even after manipulations to obtain them, the application was able to gain access only after granting the mysql_native_password rights to the account. Maybe it will help someone:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=CONCAT('*', UPPER(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1('password'))))), plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root' AND Host='localhost';
```

the full sequence of steps to change the password and its format is here:
[MySQL: How to reset or change the MySQL root password?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16556497/mysql-how-to-reset-or-change-the-mysql-root-password/62659626#62659626)