# Laravel SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused but tinker works

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I have a production site using Database from an Amazon Server, I have two more sites on the same server and both of them connects without issues.

On this particular site the connection to mysql is not working, I thought that the env file was missing or not being see by the laravel app but is not the case, when I run `php artisan tinker` and try any command it works:

```
DB::table('categories')->get();
=> Illuminate\Support\Collection {#842
     all: [
       {#828
         +"id": 1,
         +"parent_id": null,
         +"order": 1,
         +"name": "Noticias",
         +"slug": "noticias",
         +"created_at": "2018-01-09 19:26:32",
         +"updated_at": "2018-01-09 19:26:32",
       },
     ],
   }
```

The App::environment() method also works:

```
>>> App::environment();
=> "production"
```

The env files clearly says `APP_DEBUG=false` but it is returning a lot of debug, it is like the webserver is not reading the env file besides the artisan is.

This is driving me crazy because it started failing by itself, nothing was changed on the server or the code, it's the only project that is failing.

What else can I check?

```
[2018-08-25 12:22:04] production.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused {"exception":"[object] (PDOException(code: 2002): SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused at /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:67)
[stacktrace]
#0 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php(67): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=127....', 'root', 'C4f2469dcF!', Array)
#1 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php(43): Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\Connector->createPdoConnection('mysql:host=127....', 'root', 'C4f2469dcF!', Array)
#2 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/MySqlConnector.php(24): Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\Connector->createConnection('mysql:host=127....', Array, Array)
#3 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/ConnectionFactory.php(183): Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\MySqlConnector->connect(Array)
#4 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\ConnectionFactory->Illuminate\\Database\\Connectors\\{closure}()
#5 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(915): call_user_func(Object(Closure))
#6 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(940): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->getPdo()
#7 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(399): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->getReadPdo()
#8 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(325): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->getPdoForSelect(true)
#9 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(657): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->Illuminate\\Database\\{closure}('select * from `...', Array)
#10 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(624): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->runQueryCallback('select * from `...', Array, Object(Closure))
#11 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php(333): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->run('select * from
`...', Array, Object(Closure))
#12 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(1719): Illuminate\\Database\\Connection->select('select
* from `...', Array, true)
#13 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php(1704): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->runSelect()
#14 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(483): Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder->get(Array)
#15 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php(467): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder->getModels(Array)
#16 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php(360): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder->get(Array)
#17 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/app/Category.php(13): Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model::all()
#18 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/Repository.php(327): App\\Category::App\\{closure}()
#19 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Cache/CacheManager.php(304): Illuminate\\Cache\\Repository->remember('list-categories', NULL, Object(Closure))
#20 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(221): Illuminate\\Cache\\CacheManager->__call('remember', Array)
#21 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/app/Category.php(20): Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::__callStatic('remember', Array)
#22 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/routes/web.php(150): App\\Category::getCategories()
#23 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(389): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Routing\\Router))
#24 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(349): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->loadRoutes(Object(Closure))
#25 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php(221): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->group(Array, Object(Closure))
#26 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/routes/web.php(162): Illuminate\\Support\\Facades\\Facade::__callStatic('group', Array)
#27 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(393): require('/var/www/turico...')
#28 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(349): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->loadRoutes('/var/www/turico...')
#29 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/RouteRegistrar.php(105): Illuminate\\Routing\\Router->group(Array, '/var/www/turico...')
#30 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php(56): Illuminate\\Routing\\RouteRegistrar->group('/var/www/turico...')
#31 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php(40): App\\Providers\\RouteServiceProvider->mapWebRoutes()
#32 [internal function]: App\\Providers\\RouteServiceProvider->map()
#33 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#34 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#35 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#36 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(549): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#37 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Support/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php(74): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#38 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Support/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php(33): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Support\\Providers\\RouteServiceProvider->loadRoutes()
#39 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php(28): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Support\\Providers\\RouteServiceProvider->boot()
#40 [internal function]: App\\Providers\\RouteServiceProvider->boot()
#41 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(29): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#42 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(87): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::Illuminate\\Container\\{closure}()
#43 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/BoundMethod.php(31): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::callBoundMethod(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Object(Closure))
#44 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(549): Illuminate\\Container\\BoundMethod::call(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application), Array, Array, NULL)
#45 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(792): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->call(Array)
#46 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(775): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->bootProvider(Object(App\\Providers\\RouteServiceProvider))
#47 [internal function]: Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->Illuminate\\Foundation\\{closure}(Object(App\\Providers\\RouteServiceProvider), 26)
#48 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(776): array_walk(Array, Object(Closure))
#49 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/BootProviders.php(17): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->boot()
#50 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(213): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\BootProviders->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application))
#51 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(162): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#52 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(146): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->bootstrap()
#53 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#54 /var/app/html/releases/20180824022105/public/index.php(55): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))
#55 {main}
"}
```

Comment: what your logs says?

Comment: @Ggg updated the question with the log output

Comment: God! I see the is trying to connect with a credentials that are not present on the env, where it is getting them? I already did php artisan config:clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should verify if you have `bootstrap/cache/config.php` file. If yes, it means, your config is cached. Than you can run:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

to refresh config and sync data you have set in `.env` or

```
php artisan config:clear
```

if you don't want to use cached config (keep in mind it's recommended to cache config on production)

Comment: I already did that but is still trying to connect with a credentials that are not in the env file. The config.php is not present on the bootstrap/cache folder, already did php artisan config:clear php artisan cache:clear and php artisan route:clear

Comment: Is the error coming just from app or maybe from some other part of app (for example queues)? For queues you should restart them in case you made any changes after starting them.

Comment: And if it's not the case, maybe you should restart your server (maybe some settings are cached on server side?)

Comment: It's coming from the entire app, but as I said on tinker it works good

Comment: I have the same issue. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was to restart the laravel development server, ie: run `php artisan serve` again.

I had changed the db config after I had originally run the dev server.

Comment: However this doesnt impact the remote server? Locally the connection to my local database works great. But with the new settings my remote server wont connect to my remote database. The details to login work on `mysqlworkbench` to get in.

Comment: @Otto I think perhaps you need to have two different .env files in the root of your project. One of which should contain the settings for your local environment & database, the other for your remote environment & db. 

Ensure that only the .env file for the remote environment is deployed to your server!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I installed php7.2-mysql after I installed everything else. Tinker was working perfectly but my application would not connect.

I spent 2 hours trying to debug until a simple apache restart did the trick.

Comment: I am working with nginx and I have restarted nginx multiple times. Nothing sadly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that mysql's `root` user can't be used anymore, since mysql v5.7. More about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36909790/6118794).

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan cache:clear 
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

then run your mysql server and run

```
php artisan migrate
```