# Laravel - Migrations work but post requests throw "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'"

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to put a project to production. I'm getting an access error when running an Axios post request to the Laravel API. (I'm not getting this error on the local machine)

```
[2019-01-28 12:18:04] local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (SQL: select * from `oauth_clients` where `id` = 2 limit 1) {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException(code: 1698): SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (SQL: select * from `oauth_clients` where `id` = 2 limit 1) at /var/www/html/RemApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664, PDOException(code: 1698): SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' at /var/www/html/RemApp/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:68)
```

I'm not getting an error when running migrations.
Below is my .env file. (I have not changed the config/database.php)

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=AppName
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=mypasswordhere
```

1. Tried clearing cache with:

   ```
   php artisan cache:clear
   php artisan config:clear
   ```
2. Removed quotes from DB_PASSWORD
3. The credentials are correct. (Can login and run queries using mysql -u -p)

Comment: I'm using a digital ocean ubuntu droplet if this helps.

Comment: Is your production database not password protected ? You can run this `.env` on both environments and it would still connect to 2 different databases

Comment: Don't deploy a application to a production environment on your own if you don't have system administration experience.  I doubt this problem is programming related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this was related to: [SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'. Tried everything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36864206/sqlstatehy000-1698-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-tried-everythi)

For some reason a mysql root user cannot be used. To solve this you would need to create a new user. Below are the commands to create a new user and grant root privileges.

```
mysql -u root -p
CREATE USER 'username'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'localhost';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit
service mysql restart
```

Now edit your .env to match the new user credentials. To be on the safe side you can reboot the server.

Answer (score 0):

If the db password is empty, don't put an empty string, leave it blank, as such, change:

```
DB_PASSWORD=''
```

To

```
DB_PASSWORD=
```

otherwise, it passes those quotes as your password.

**Edit #1**

If you do have a password, then unquote it if it is quoted.

Comment: I removed the password just for stack overflow. I have it in the original .env

Comment: @Vova is your password quoted? If so, don't quote it.

Answer (score 0):

Just set up correct Database credentials:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql 
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1 
DB_PORT=3306 
DB_DATABASE=        // Your Database Name
DB_USERNAME=       // Yout Database Username
DB_PASSWORD=      // Your Database Password
```

If no password is set on the database, clear it `DB_PASSWORD`, empty space must also be removed

After completion of `.env` edit, You can clear the configuration cache with the following artisan command: `php artisan config:cache`

you need also restart your server after changing your `.env` file values.

Comment: I removed the password just for stack overflow. I have it in the original .env

Comment: @Vova please clear cache: `php artisan config:cache`

Comment: @Vova If all possible solution is not working for you then please provide some more information. 
make sure have you a default username(**root**) in the installation of MySQL ?

Comment: What exactly is "this"? Can you explain what you've changed and how that might solve the problem?

Comment: @NicoHaase I gave my answer Op on the basis of editing the previous question, OP have changed question view, yes i will explain answer but i will first out find out solution because op have tried this solution but is not work for him [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54402070/revisions)

Comment: I understand that it is difficult to adopt an answer while the question has changed, and surely one should appreciate that you try to find a new solution. But regardless of the question, "try this"-answers without an explanation are not as good as those which contain an explanation

Comment: Okay, thanks for your time @NicoHaase , I will take care of it next time :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, using the root with empty password on production is dangers. You need to use a separate user with strong password or at least use strong password for root.

and clear cache on production

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: Can you even explain why exactly it is "dangers" and how that comment solves the original problem?

Comment: The comment about using strong password is a recommendation.

Comment: So, your answer is a recommendation that does not solve the problem?

Comment: My answer includes recommendation regarding a security issue and solution for the problem.