# Access denied for 'root'@'localhost'

Tags: php, mysql

I'm making an app with Laravel, and when I try to run a migration, I get this error.

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (SQL: create table `migrations` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment primary key, `migration` varchar(255) not null, `batch` int not null) default character set utf8mb4 collate 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci')
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQLSTATE\[HY000\] \[1698\] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36864206/sqlstatehy000-1698-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost)

Comment: Use some GUI client like phpMyAdmin and check if you have root account and it accepts connections from localhost.

Comment: @esqew no, that didn't work

Comment: @biesior how can I install phpMyAdmin on Pop OS

Comment: Go to phpmyadmin.net and read user's manual. On the other hand while you're on Linux you can easily go to terminal and run mysql client there

Answer (score 0):

1. Check user details in `.env` file. You should have
   user credentials in `.env` and user with them in sql(use
   phpmyadmin to simplify process)

```html
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=Database
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

2. Run in your app folder the `php artisan config:cache` command, if you sure that user credentials are correct in `.env`

Comment: what is phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, I ended up creating a new user just for the laravel app.